# PHP define(K, V) referencing issue

Tags: php

I'm attempting to set directories in my PHP file and decided I was going to use define(K,V), however I've run into a problem:

```
define('ROOTDIR', explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR , __FILE__));
define('FORUMPATH', ROOTDIR . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "forum" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

While ROOTDIR returns properly, FORUMPATH does not, instead FORUMPATH returns

```
ROOTDIR/forum/
```

instead of

```
/usr/www/name/public/forum/
```

I don't really understand why, from my understanding of the define feature this should work, as-long as I define the keys in order, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The return value of a explode statement is a array! So you try to explode your __FILE__ with / and want to define a constant as a array and use the the entire array as a string!

Comment: if you had error reporting enabled you'd see `Warning: Constants may only evaluate to scalar values`

Comment: Did you downV my answer? My answer works and is also the shortest one with 1 line: `define('FORUMPATH', __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "forum" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was mentioned, `explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR , __FILE__)` results to an array. I cannot give you a concrete solution without knowing what do you mean under root directory, but for example if you would like to set it to the directory of the executed file, you can use `__DIR__`.

```
define('ROOTDIR', __DIR__));
define('FORUMPATH', ROOTDIR . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "forum" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

Anyway, just calculate a string for the `ROOTDIR`.

Comment: Added an example @Marwelln, but I think it was way too obvious :)

Comment: Thanks, my main problem was my error reporting was disabled for some reason and I didn't get the warning message as posted by andrew. `Warning: Constants may only evaluate to scalar values` once he posted this I instantly understoof what the problem was, thanks for your answer though, as it does demonstrate a correct implementation.

Comment: @Christian.tucker Error reporting you can turn on with: `<?php
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
 ?>` And why did you accept his answer? Just out of curiosity

Answer (score -3):

This should work:

```
define('ROOTDIR', str_replace(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .basename(__FILE__), "",__FILE__)); 
define('FORUMPATH', ROOTDIR . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "forum" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

Or you can make it simple like this:

```
define('FORUMPATH', __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "forum" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

Comment: `__FILE__` is a string, it cannot be imploded.

Comment: It should work if the above code in placed in `index.php`. In other cases, not :)